# Mime Types (Restricting/Allow application/octet-stream which is .bin and .rar

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types

So I run this type of code in my wp
$filetype = wp_check_filetype($_POST['file']);
        $type = $_FILES['file'];

```
    if($type['type'] == 'application/x-zip-compressed'){

    }else{
        if($type['type'] == 'application/octet-stream'){
```

and I come up with small issue that I can't get around...The problem is that we allow .rar .zip only to be uploaded on the server however application/octet-stream is .bin which we do not accept. I wonder if there is a way of stopping the .bin file while application/octet-stream is in act. appreciate any help

Comment: as far as I know, you can restrict partially the functionality on the browser based on the extension of the file, but in doesn't mean that someone can change the extension and upload it as a .rar

Comment: You can restrict by extension using PHP's **path_info** function as well `$file_parts = path_info($_FILES['file']); $extension = $file_parts['extension']` , but as @Heinrich mentioned, extensions can be changed.... [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php